# Using objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been working on Javascript in codecademy and have a doubt on one of the questions.

Question:

Write two functions:

```
one creates an object from arguments
the other modifies that object
```

My answer:

```
//First, the object creator
function makeGamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
    //should return an object with three keys:
    // name
    // totalScore
    // gamesPlayed
    var myObject = {
     "name": name,
     "totalscore" : totalscore,
     "gamesPlayed" : gamesPlayed
    };
  return myObject;
}

//Now the object modifier
function addGameToPlayer(player,score) {
    //should increment gamesPlayed by one
    //and add score to totalScore
    //of the gamePlayer object passed in as player
    var score = player[totalscore];
    score =score+1;
    player[totalscore] = score;
}
```

Not sure where my error is. Need some guidance on improving this solution.. Many Thanks...

Comment: what's the question? if you don't know what the error is, we are supposed to guess it?

Comment: You say you have to add `score` to `player.totalscore`, but you're assigning `score + 1` to `player.totalscore` instead. Also, be wary of brackets notation, as it requires strings: `player["totalscore"]`, not `player[totalscore]`.

Comment: You should read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScri) alongside with doing the exercises. Especially have a look at [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your object you are never assigning the score

```
"totalscore" : totalscore,
```

should be

```
"totalscore" : totalScore
```

since you are passing in `totalScore`

Answer (score 3):

You are not accessing the object correctly, either

```
var score = player.totalscore;
```

or

```
var score = player["totalscore"];
```

It expects a string, but you are passing an undefined variable.

You are also defining `score` twice within the function, use a different name for the internal variable.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to `makeGamePlayer` is named `totalScore` but you are using `totalscore` in `myObject` which is a different name  - case matters.

You also have an issue in `addGameToPlayer` trying to use a variable named `totalscore` but that is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the typo's and your code being rather silly and pointless IMO (sorry, but google Douglas Crockford JavaScript Object or something and *read* what a powerconstructor is), I gather you want to check if all parameters are passed to the function. If so:

```
function foo (bar, foobar)
{
    if (arguments.length < 2)
    {
        throw new Error('foo expects 2 arguments, only '+arguments.length+' were specified');
    }
    //or - default values:
    bar = bar || 'defaultBar';
    //check the type?
    if (typeof bar !== 'string' || typeof foobar !== 'number')
    {
        throw new Error ('types don\'t match expected types');
    }
}
```

And so on... But please, read and be more specific when asking a question